# How can I increase the space between letters in a text object?

Tags: text-object

If I just make a space with the space key it will add too much space not equal like the other letters spaces between each other. But without a space the Y and the T seems like they are glued together.

[image: T and Y almost glued]

And if I make one space with the space key then the space is not equal to the other spaces between the letters:

[image: Space is not equal to the others]

And it's only with the last Y letter.

I tried to move the text a bit with the arrow keys like in the solution but then in the render windows CTRL + F12 the text is now too big :

[image: Too big]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In edit mode navigate text cursor before the last letter Y. Then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and use arrow keys to move all text after cursor to the position, that you want.

Comment: I did but now when rendering CTRL + F12 the text in the render window is very big too big for the sides. I added a screenshot of it to my question.  and I only moved the text with the arrows a little bit.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.